# Using Applescript to right-click on Application file

Tags: applescript

I cannot seem to find an answer to how to write my applescript to

Right-Click on a listing in the Applications Folder to open the Get Info option window to open to read in the Version field so I can compare it against my expect value.

I have spent about 6 hours, and I am kind of a noob.  I can understand what is happening once I see it, but creating from scratch is just taking a long time for me.  Thanks.

Comment: on selectfile(ProgramName, WindowName, FileName) --("Finder", "Applications", "Osirix")
  set ReadFileName to 0
  set TheRow to 2
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process ProgramName
      repeat until ReadFileName is equal to FileName
        set FileName to value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row TheRow of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window WindowName as text
        set TheRow to TheRow + 1
        tell FileName to perform action "AXShowMenu"
      end repeat
    end tell
  end tell
  return TheRow
end selectfile

Comment: You may be better off with `do shell script` after trying this in Terminal `mdls -name kMDItemVersion /path/to/YourUnspecifiedSecretApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ugly GUI scripting, every application even without AppleScript dictionary responds to the `version` property

```
set appVersion to version of application "Maps"
```

Comment: Nice answer - as usual! When are you going to write the book of all this cool stuff that no-one can ever find on Apple's developer docs?

Comment: @MarkSetchell From the [AppleScript Release notes 10.5(2007!)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_5/RN-10_5.html): *Most applications have a `version` property of their own, but using it requires that the application be running, and sometimes you specifically want to avoid that. The new built-in `version` property will return the application version as text without launching the application or sending it an event. There is also a corresponding built-in `name` property; the value is usable as the name of an application to `tell`.*

Comment: `10 PRINT "ROFL" 20 GOTO 10`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Although I would still like to know how to do it the 'hard way' so that I can learn a little bit more.